# Adding new item with EF with identity column

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

How can I add a new entity with EF where I have `Id` column which is defined as `identity` in the database ?

I get the following error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'AppsData'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

But I cannot set the `Id` to null, as it's an `int` in the database (not even nullable)

My function is:

```
    public Conduit.Mam.MaMDBEntityFramework.AppsData Add(Conduit.Mam.MaMDBEntityFramework.AppsData item)
    {   
        maMdbEntities.AddToAppsDatas(item);

        maMdbEntities.SaveChanges();

        return item;
    }
```

Comment: Did you make that column identity increment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to make this attribute `identity` in the edmx as well

Answer (score 2):

If you are setting Id with any integer value except zero than remove that initialization or set it to zero.

As the exception is clearly saying that you have a value for your Id column, which is identity column.

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'AppsData'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Exception

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated

only comes when your sending data length is greater than db table column datatype lenght.

Comment: It solved my problem but araised a new one:`String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: @EladBenda, You are sending a string or binary value which length is greater then in your db table column value, Please check that.

Answer (score 2):

String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

This means: data you want to insert in the column more then column size. Increase column size in db.